# Category of modules over a ring without unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring without unity, then an $A$-module is an abelian group $M$ with the action of $A$, but without the assumption that the identity of $A$ acts trivially because $A$ has no identity element.

Let $\tilde{A} = A \times \mathbb{Z}$ with addition defined coordinate wise, and product:

$$  (a,\lambda) \cdot (b,\mu)=(ab+\mu a + \lambda b, \lambda \mu)   $$

is a ring with unity $(0,1)$.
Then an $A$-module M is also an $\tilde{A}$-module (with the identity acting trivially) through:

$$  (a,\lambda) \cdot m = am+\lambda m   $$

Then there are two categories defined, $Mod(A)$ and $Mod(\tilde{A})$.

Are they equivalent?

Does it still works if we change $A$ for a $k$-algebra where $k$ is a field and $\mathbb{Z}$ for $k$?

Comment: Yes and yes. ${}$

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: How can I prove that? or where can I read it? I think I just gave the definition on objects of a candidate to be an equivalence, but I have no idea on how to define the quasi inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These categories are not just equivalent but isomorphic.  You have defined an operation on objects $Mod(A)\to Mod(\tilde{A})$, and it is easy to see that it also preserves maps and so gives a functor; the inverse is simply given by taking an $\tilde{A}$-module and restricting its module structure to $A\subset\tilde{A}$.  More generally, this works with $\mathbb{Z}$ replaced by any commutative ring $R$, with $A$ an $R$-algebra.